# How to change my HTML input to div class

Tags: html, css

How am I going to change my current input to div class? I would like to change my current user profile picture from the bottom design.

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.beirutnightlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/David-Beckham_89.jpg" name="image" width="85" height="85" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" href="#changepic" class="ttip_b thumbnail"></input>

<div class="round-pic2" style="background-image: url('http://www.beirutnightlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/David-Beckham_89.jpg');"></div>
```

CSS style

```
.round-pic2 {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0em auto;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
border-radius: 99em;
-webkit-border-radius: 99em;
-moz-border-radius: 99em;
border: 0px solid gray;
box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yy6N5/

Answer (score 1):

Just `input{}` or `input[type="image"]{}` will do:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy6N5/1/)

```
input{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0em auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 99em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
    -moz-border-radius: 99em;
    border: 0px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Also you can add class on your `input`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy6N5/3/)

```
<input class="round-pic2" type="image" src="http://www.beirutnightlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/David-Beckham_89.jpg" name="image" width="85" height="85" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" href="#changepic" class="ttip_b thumbnail"></input>
```

Comment: If I'm doing this the image are not display in correct position since I'm using `ttip_b` `thumbnail` class for the input. Also possible the css style only for this input?

Comment: @user206530 Yes, just add `class="round-pic2"` to your input. See updated fiddle.

Comment: I follow the your changes but I can see the submit text and the line on the profile picture. http://i62.tinypic.com/2lvipn5.png but I have set the `font-size:1px` to hide the Submit value. But now I'm not able to fix the line displayed on my profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the class of the input type="image" as a selector:

```
.ttip_b, .round-pic2  {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0em auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 99em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
    -moz-border-radius: 99em;
    border: 0px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

But I think, giving it an id attribute is better. 
Cheers!

Comment: This is right as well since he already set a class name `class="ttip_b thumbnail"`

Comment: @witherwind unable to clear the text and line on my profile picture. Also I did use `text-indent:-9999px;` http://i62.tinypic.com/2lvipn5.png